# R Webscraping RCurl and httr Content

Tags: html, web-scraping, rvest, rcurl, httr

I'm learning a bit about webscraping and I'm having a little doubt regarding 2 packages (httr and RCurl), I'm trying to get a code from a magazine (ISSN) on the researchgate website and I came across a situation. When extracting the content from the site by httr and RCurl, I get the ISSN in the RCurl package and in httr my function is returning NULL, could anyone tell me why this? in my opinion it was for both functions to be working. Follow the code below.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(RCurl)

url <- "https://www.researchgate.net/journal/0730-0301_Acm_Transactions_On_Graphics"

########
# httr #
########

conexao <- GET(url)
conexao_status <- http_status(conexao)
conexao_status

content(conexao, as = "text", encoding = "utf-8") %>% read_html() -> webpage1

ISSN <- webpage1 %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[7]/td') %>%
  html_text %>%
  str_to_title() %>%
  str_split(" ") %>%
  unlist
ISSN

########
# RCurl #
########

options(RCurlOptions = list(verbose = FALSE, 
                            capath = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"), 
                            ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))

webpage <- getURLContent(url) %>% read_html()

ISSN <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[7]/td') %>%
  html_text %>%
  str_to_title() %>%
  str_split(" ") %>%
  unlist
ISSN
```

> > sessionInfo() R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build
> >     9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
>   [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:  [1] testit_0.7      dplyr_0.7.4
>   progress_1.1.2  readxl_1.1.0    stringr_1.3.0   RCurl_1.95-4.10
>   bitops_1.0-6     [8] httr_1.3.1      rvest_0.3.2     xml2_1.2.0
>   jsonlite_1.5
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_0.12.16
>   bindr_0.1.1       magrittr_1.5      R6_2.2.2          rlang_0.2.0
>   tools_3.5.0        [7] yaml_2.1.19       assertthat_0.2.0 
>   tibble_1.4.2      bindrcpp_0.2.2    curl_3.2          glue_1.2.0
>   [13] stringi_1.1.7     pillar_1.2.2      compiler_3.5.0
>   cellranger_1.1.0  prettyunits_1.0.2 pkgconfig_2.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the content type is JSON and not HTML, you can't use `read_html()` on it:

```
> conexao
Response [https://www.researchgate.net/journal/0730-0301_Acm_Transactions_On_Graphics]
Date: 2018-06-02 03:15
Status: 200
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Size: 328 kB
```

Use `fromJSON()` instead to extract issn:

```
library(jsonlite)
result <- fromJSON(content(conexao, as = "text", encoding = "utf-8") )
result$result$data$journalFullInfo$data$issn
```

result:

```
> result$result$data$journalFullInfo$data$issn
[1] "0730-0301"
```